# Viewing dynamic pages with Rails and Nginx/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

So, I installed Nginx with Phusion Passenger support for my Rails app via this [guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app). I'm running it on Ubuntu 12.0.4.

I set up a virtual host entry pointing to my Rails app directory like so `root /srv/www/app/public;`. That works fine for serving up static pages in the public directory, but I'm not clear on how I would serve up the dynamic views that I would normally be using with Rails. I've tried setting `root` to `/srv/www/app` instead but I just get a "403 forbidden" page. I feel like I'm missing something rather obvious here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the privileges of Rails root folder with

```
ls -all
```

Make sure that user that nginx is using has right for access.
User used is listed near top of config file with keyword 'user'.

Comment: Thanks. The folder was owned by root, but the nginx user was www-data.